# Application crashing on return statement from jni without error message

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I am writing an engine which does huge amount of calculations.
The engine is written in c/c++  and returns a 3-d double array to the native.
When i try to run the application the native gives a call through the jni to c code which performs all the calculations and on the return statement the application crashes.
The code for the same is

The prototype declarations is :

```
JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL Java_com_example_testbi_MainActivity_EngineCalculations
   (JNIEnv *env,jobject this)
```

after which the main calculations are done and then the return logic is :

```
    doubleArrayClass = (*env)->FindClass(env,"[[D");
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "Engine","\n!* doubleArrayClass declared..."); 
     innerdoubleArrayClass = (*env)->FindClass(env,"[D");
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "Engine","\n!* innerdoubleArrayClass declared..."); 
     returnArray = (*env)->NewObjectArray(env,5,doubleArrayClass,NULL);

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "Engine","\n!* returnArray declared..."); 
    for(i = 0;i < 3;i ++)
    {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "Engine","\n!* inside for loop of i...%d",i); 
             outerArray = (*env)->NewObjectArray(env,ProductDetails.iPolicyTerm+1,innerdoubleArrayClass,NULL);
            for(j = 0;j <= ProductDetails.iPolicyTerm;j ++)
            {
                __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "Engine","\n!* inside for loop of j...%d",j); 
                 doubleArray = (*env) -> NewDoubleArray(env,15);
                if(i == 0 || i == 1)
                {
                    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "Engine","\n!* inside if loop of i :%d",i); 
                    (*env) -> SetDoubleArrayRegion(env,doubleArray,0,15,(jdouble*)dReturnArray[i][j]);
                }
                if(i == 2)
                {
                    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "Engine","\n!* inside if loop of i :%d",i); 
                    (*env) -> SetDoubleArrayRegion(env,doubleArray,0,2,(jdouble*)dOtherCalculatedValues[j]);
                }

                (*env) -> SetObjectArrayElement(env,outerArray,(jsize)j,doubleArray);

                (*env) -> DeleteLocalRef(env,doubleArray);

            }
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "Engine","\n!* completed j loop ..."); 
        (*env) -> SetObjectArrayElement(env,returnArray,(jsize)i,outerArray);
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "Engine","\n!* completed j loop .2nd time.."); 
        (*env) -> DeleteLocalRef(env,outerArray);
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "Engine","\n!* completed DeleteLocalRef"); 
    }
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "Engine","\n!* returning retuirn array...."); 

}

return returnArray;
```

The log I see is :

> 01-27 09:53:39.272: I/Engine(4594): !* inside if loop of i :2
>
> 01-27 09:53:39.272: I/Engine(4594): !* completed j loop ...
>
> 01-27 09:53:39.272: I/Engine(4594): !* completed j loop .2nd time..
>
> 01-27 09:53:39.272: I/Engine(4594): !* completed DeleteLocalRef
>
> 01-27 09:53:39.272: I/Engine(4594): !* returning retuirn array....

after which the application crashes.

Comment: could you show the error, or how your application crash!!

Comment: There is no error message or exception just the last printf before return statement is seen in the log after which the application is crashing

Comment: Check your calling convention. and make sure you not corrupting the `jenv` while using it as well as *properly* initializing your out-params.